# Dictionary comprehension with keys and values

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm trying to create a dictionary object with keys being people's names and values being sum of all scores by each individual

> Here is the base list called scores. As you can see each element of the meta list is also a list containing tuples of names and scores

```
[[('Sebastian Vettel', 25),
('Lewis Hamilton', 18),
('Kimi Raikkonen', 15),
('Daniel Ricciardo', 12),
('Fernando Alonso', 10),
('Max Verstappen', 8),
('Nico Hulkenberg', 6),
('Valtteri Bottas', 4),
('Stoffel Vandoorne', 2),
('Carlos Sainz', 1)],

[('Sebastian Vettel', 25),
('Valtteri Bottas', 18),
('Lewis Hamilton', 15),
('Pierre Gasly', 12),
('Kevin Magnussen', 10),
('Nico Hulkenberg', 8),
('Fernando Alonso', 6), ...
```

**I want to create a dictionary that contains unique names as keys, and sum of all scores as values ordered (in descending) by sum of scores. Also I'd like to limit the dictionary to Top 3 total score**

> Here's my attempt so far, but seems to be missing something.

```
scores_total = defaultdict(int)

for (name,score) in scores:
    key = name
    values = score
    scores_total[key] += int(score)

scores_total
```

> But I get this error: ValueError Traceback (most recent call last)
>    in ()
>         1 scores_total = defaultdict(int)
>         2 
>         3 for (name,score) in scores:
>         4     key = name
>         5     values = score ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)

Any idea how to tackle this? Much appreciating help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first make a dictionary with all the scores summed as values for each person, then make a list that sorts the keys by the value which is now the sum, in reverse to get largest to smallest. Then slice that list for only three `[:3]` and create a dictionary using those names as keys retrieving the values from the old dictionary .

```
d = {}
for i in scores:
    for j in i:
        if j[0] not in d:
            d[j[0]] = j[1]
        else:
            d[j[0]] += j[1]

l = sorted(d, key=lambda x: d[x], reverse = True)

final = {i: d[i] for i in l[:3]}
print(final)
```

> ```
> {'Sebastian Vettel': 50, 'Lewis Hamilton': 33, 'Valtteri Bottas': 22}
> ```

Comment: thank you it worked out magically. I just can't seem to get my head around multiple for clause like for I in scores: for j in I... Guessing it will come more naturally to me with more practice

Comment: @jtossw your welcome! Cheers :) yeah you just gotta look at it since it’s nested lists `i ` represents each list then you need to access the items of each `i` so that would be `j in i`

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little lost on your explanation, but here's what I'm getting.

Let's say this was for let's say soccer games and these 'scores' are for players goals made, right? And I'm also going to assume the use of the separate lists is for different games.

With this, you're trying to get an "overview" of them all in one 'neat' `dict` right? If that's so, you've got a good start. I'd use:

```
from sortedcontainers import SortedList #this fixes your top 3 question

games = [
    [('name', score), ('name', score)...], #game 1
    [('name', score), ('name', score)] # game 2
]

scores_review = defaultdict(SortedList) #makes a sorted list as the dafault for the dict

for game in games:
    for name, score in scores: #no need to wrap name, score in parentheses
        scores_total[name].add(score)
```

Now the `scores_review` variable is a dict with lists of all their scores for every game and it's sorted. This means to get the top 3 for someone you just use:

```
top_three = scores_review['name'][-3:]
```

And to get the sum just use:

```
all_scores = sum(scores_review['name'])
```